# MimeType how to get a filename

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, mime-types

I'm currently working on Drag n Drop feature for my app on MACOSx using Qt/C++

I have implemented the drag n drop to move file from mac to the app. the mechanism seems working but how can I get the filename of what I'm dragging in the app.

Currently what I have when selecting a file on my desktop and Drag'ndrop it in my app is the mimeData.

```
 const QMimeData* mimeData = event->mimeData();
```

Using the code below, I'm extraction data.

```
QList<QUrl> urlList = mimeData->urls();
QByteArray appData;

for (int i = 0; i < urlList.size() && i < 32; ++i)
{
    pathList.append(urlList.at(i).toLocalFile());
}
```

But the file is names : file://1122121.D (sorry not sure exactly about the syntax, but I think that I'm getting the id of the file in my FS, but how to extract the real name + path : such as /Users/xxx/Desktop/toto.txt instead of file:///...

Thanks

Comment: this is a Qt issues because I'm using Yosemite on OSX :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093697/os-x-yosemite-qt-drag-and-drop-file-name-bug